# Formatting data from a database in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, database, typescript

I am having trouble with writing the following method on an Angular class.  I don't know how to add values from `arrayId` to the `data` array in the `series` object.

```
getChartOptions() {

    const arrayId=[];
    const arrayTimestamp=[];
    const arrayData=[];
    const arrayData2=[];
    var i=0;

    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://prod.kaisens.fr:811/api/sleep/?deviceid=93debd97-6564-454b-be33-35bd377a2563&startdate=1612310400000&enddate=1614729600000').subscribe(
      reponse => {
        this.sleeps = reponse;
        this.sleeps.forEach(element => { arrayId.push(this.sleeps[i]._id),arrayTimestamp.push(this.sleeps[i].timestamp),arrayData.push(this.sleeps[i].data[18]),arrayData2.push(this.sleeps[i].data[39])
          i++;
        });
         console.log(arrayId);
         console.log(arrayTimestamp);
         console.log(arrayData);
         console.log(arrayData2);
      }
    )
    return {
      series: [{
        name: 'Id',
        data: [35, 65, 75, 55, 45, 60, 55]
      }]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two main pieces of advice for you:

1. Know the types of that data that you are dealing with.
2. Get familiar with all of the various [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods).

`get<any>()` is not a helpful type.  If you understand what the response is then Typescript can help ensure that you are handling it correctly.

I checked out the URL and it looks like you get an array of objects like this:

```
{
    "_id": 4,
    "device_id": "93debd97-6564-454b-be33-35bd377a2563",
    "timestamp": 1612310400000.0,
    "data": "{'sleep_quality': 1, 'sleep_duration': 9}"
},
```

That `data` property is not properly encoded as an object or as a parseable JSON string.  If you control this backend then you will want to fix that.

At first I thought that the `data[18]` and `data[39]` in your code were mistakes.  Now I see that it as attempt to extract values from this malformed data.  Accessing by index won't work if these numbers can be 10 or more.

The type that you have now is:

```
interface DataPoint {
    _id: number;
    device_id: string;
    timestamp: number;
    data: string;
}
```

The type that you want is:

```
interface DataPoint {
    _id: number;
    device_id: string;
    timestamp: number;
    data: {
        sleep_quality: number;
        sleep_duration: number;
    }
}
```

You can type the request as `this.httpClient.get<DataPoint[]>(` and now you'll get autocomplete on the data.

---

It looks like what you are trying to do is basically to convert this from one array of rows to a separate array for each column.

You do not need the variable `i` because the `.forEach` loop handles the iteration.  The `element` variable in the callback is the row that you want.

```
this.sleeps.forEach(element => { 
    arrayId.push(element._id);
    arrayTimestamp.push(element.timestamp);
    arrayData.push(element.data[18]);
    arrayData2.push(element.data[39]);
});
```

The `.forEach` loop that you have now is efficient because it only loops through the array once.  A `.map` for each column is technically less efficient because we have to loop through separately for each column, but I think it might make the code easier to read and understand.  It also allows Typescript to infer the types of the arrays.  Whereas with an empty array you would need to annotate it like `const arrayId: number[] = [];`.

```
const mapData = (response: DataPoint[]) => {
    return [{
        name: 'Id',
        data: response.map(element => element._id)
    }, {
        name: 'Timestamp',
        data: response.map(element => element.timestamp)
    }, {
        name: 'Sleep Quality',
        data: response.map(element => parseInt(element.data[18])) // fix this
    }, {
        name: 'Sleep Duration',
        data: response.map(element => parseInt(element.data[39])) // fix this
    }]
}
```

The HTTP request is asynchronous.  If you access your array outside of the `subscribe` callback then they are still empty.  I'm not an angular person so this part I'm unsure of, but I think that you want to be updating a property on your class instead of returning the value?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this piece of code:

```
series: [{
name: 'Id',
data: arrayId
}]
```